# JOOQ with ASP.NET and SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, jooq

Does jooq work with ASP.net and SQL Server? If yes, can someone show what does the code look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, dejan! Asking for full code on making a framework and library work well together is a bit broad for this site. If you're having a problem with your setup, please edit your post to include relevant details about your end goal, what you've already done and what your configuration looks like, and we'll be happy to help you find and fix the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) officially supports SQL Server 2008 and 2012. Being a Java library, .NET is currently not officially supported. In the future, a formal .NET port might be on the roadmap, but is not a priority right now.

Some jOOQ users have reported to have successfully used jOOQ with [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/). Details can be seen in this [thread on the jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/LZy5hoRjonA/cQCV_NIxuAAJ).

Answer (score 2):

jOOQ appears to be a Java library, so out of the box I would say no, it would not work out ASP.NET. 
SQL Server is  listed on their website at the present time so, I would say it is supported .

Perhaps Entity Framework would work for you?

Comment: Well, I'm learning asp.net using SQL server, or mysql. And, this year I had difficults to found "how could user update server sql tables on client side when leaving application", without security browser problems like pop-up or activeX setups. Currently, I have one training application when user leave, or close page it redirect to application page which fires sql script on Page Load.

Comment: But, of course this brings many issues when client close web page, and then redirect to another, as many things can happened on client site with browser window. It can crash down, and update is then not performed, or loosing internet connection and also update will not be performed, etc. With JOOQ I might see opportunity to bring more stable application, if you all undestand in the end what I mean.

Comment: I have reivewed JOOQ sites, and I must be honest that it is very poor with anykind show cases, or more detail step by steps. I'm mean there is 1-7 step guide, but or I'm not so good programmer this JOOQ is for advanced Java programmers.  I'm using Visual Studio tool which I think is globaly one of most using software (I dont want price up Microsoft).

Comment: And, I did not found any guide how to start, like install Jooq into Visual Studio, or integrate within.

Comment: @dejandejanovic there are facilities in .net to handle reliability. visual studio is mainly a .net environment and jooq is for java.

Comment: @dejandejanovic and jooq is only for building queries. .net languages have linq.

Comment: @dejandejanovic: I think your high expectations won't be met by jOOQ. There is simply no point in explaining how jOOQ could be used in Visual Studio, as jOOQ currently does not target .NET. Now, if you feel that some parts of the documentation could be improved, feel free to provide some concrete suggestions on the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user)